# What does it mean "you can’t hide the terminating delimiter of a pattern inside a regex construct" in the "Programming Perl"?

Tags: regex, perl

Sorry, but once again I need help to understand rather complicated snippet from the "Programming Perl" book. Here it is (what is obscure to me marked as **bold**):

> patterns are parsed like double-quoted strings, all the normal double-quote conventions will work, including variable interpolation  (unless you use single quotes
>   as the delimiter) and special characters indicated with backslash escapes. These are applied before the string is interpreted as a regular expression (This is one of the
>   few places in the Perl language where a string undergoes more than one pass of
>   processing). ...
>
> Another consequence of this two-pass parsing is that the ordinary Perl tokener
>   finds the end of the regular expression first, just as if it were looking for the
>   terminating delimiter of an ordinary string. Only after it has found **the end of the
>   string** (and done any variable interpolation) is the pattern treated as a regular
>   expression. Among other things, this means **you can’t “hide” the terminating
>   delimiter of a pattern inside a regex construct** (such as a bracketed character class
>   or a regex comment, which we haven’t covered yet). Perl will see the delimiter
>   wherever it is and terminate the pattern at that point.

First, why it is said that `Only after it has found the end of the string` not `the end of the regular expression` which it was looking, as stated before?

Second, what does it mean `you can’t “hide” the terminating delimiter of a pattern inside a regex construct`? Why I can't hide the terminating delimiter `/`, whereas I can place it wherever I want either in the regexp directly `/A\/C/` or in a interpolated variable (even without `\`):

```
my $s = 'A/';
my $p = 'A/C';
say $p =~ /$s/;
```

outputs `1`.

**While I was writing and re-reading my question I thought that this snippet tells about using a single-quote as a regexp delimiter, then it all seems quite cohesive. Is my assumption correct?**

My appreciation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It says "end of the string" instead of "end of the regular expression" because at that point it's treating the regex as if it were just a string.

It's trying to say that this does not work:

```
/foo[-/_]/
```

Even though normal regex metacharacters are not special inside `[]`, Perl will see the regex as `/foo[-/` and complain about an unterminated class.

It's trying to say that Perl does not parse the regex as it reads it.  First it finds the end of the regex in your source code as if it were a quoted string, so the only special character is `\`.  Then it interpolates any variables.  *Then* it parses the result as a regular expression.

You can hide the terminating delimiter with `\` because that works in ordinary strings.  You can hide the delimiter inside an interpolated variable, because interpolation happens after the delimiter is found.  If you use a bracketing delimiter (e.g. `{ }` or `[ ]`), you can nest matching pairs of delimiters inside the regex, because `q{}` works like that too.
But you can't hide it inside any other regex construct.

Comment: And even then that's not entirely true -- some regex delimiters, like `m{}`, are "special" enough to nest. For instance, `m{{}}` works. (The first `}` is *not* treated as a delimiter; only the second one is.)

Comment: @duskwuff, but again, that's a string construct, not a regex construct.  `q{{}}` works in exactly the same way; it's equivalent to `'{}'`.

Comment: Very very complicated book. It seems to me that this rather simple thing could be described in a much more digestive way.

Comment: @caligula: Don't kid yourself.  Perl parsing is complicated stuff.  Complicated enough that pretty much nothing outside of `perl` itself gets it 100% right.  The language was made by a linguistics fan, who often preferred the syntax to feel natural over its being easy to parse.

Answer (score 5):

Say you want to match a `*`. You would use

```
m/\*/
```

But what if you were using you used `*` as your delimiter? The following doesn't work:

```
m*\**
```

because it's interpreted as

```
m/*/
```

as seen in the following:

```
$ perl -e'm*\**'
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
```

---

Take the string literal

```
"a\"b"
```

It produces the string

```
a"b
```

Similarly, the match operator

```
m*a\*b*
```

produces the regex pattern

```
a*b
```

If you want to match a literal `*`, you have to use other means. In other words.

```
m*a\*b*      ===  m/a*b/       matches pattern a*b
m*a\x{2A}b*  ===  m/a\*b/      matches pattern a\*b
```

Comment: Yikes! That somebody would pick `'*'` as a delimiter!!

Comment: Oops, the text is actually talking about what @cjm mentioned. I'll leave my post undeleted because it's somewhat related.

Comment: Can you please explain why `m*\**` does not work? As I understood, first, interpreter takes `*\**` as a double-quoted string. Second, it makes interpolation and throws out `\`. Third, it treats remaining `*` as a regexp pattern. But why `\` works in `m/\*/` ? Or should I better ask a new question?